# How to specify that two buttons have same width but with a maximum?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Having two buttons, I need them to be same width, but with a maximum width.

I tried with this:

```
Row (
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(0.9f)
            .padding(4.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ){
        Button(R.string.previous, {}, Modifier.weight(1f))
        Button(R.string.next, {}, Modifier.weight(1f))
    }
```

But it makes buttons fill 50% of the container each one, so I searched how to specify a max width and tried this:

```
Modifier.widthIn(100.dp)
Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.1f)
```

None of these modifiers worked, all are ignored if you use weight. How can I use weight to specify that two buttons have same width, but with a maximum width so if the screen haves a lot of width the buttons are not giant?

Comment: Please use an English spell-checker on your posts. "Tried" has an "i" not a "y". The personal pronoun "I" is always a capital, no exceptions.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what kind of layout you need. It will be really helpful if you can add an image of the layout. But in the mean while if you need the below layout.

[image: Demo of the code snippet]

It can be achieved with the below code snippet:

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun Demo() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.White)
            .padding(4.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
    ) {
        CustomButton(text = "Previous") {}
        CustomButton(text = "Next") {}
    }
}

@Composable
fun CustomButton(
    text: String,
    maxWidth: Dp = 100.dp,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    Button(
        onClick = { onClick },
        modifier = Modifier.width(maxWidth)
    ) {
        Text(text)
    }
}
```

Comment: this answer doesn't work, because if the text of the buttons is longer than 100.dp then what? weight must be used i suposse, as I tryed on my question sample, so we are on the same point

Comment: Please add an image so that we can have better understanding of what kind of layout you want..